# Git rebase first 2 Commit

Tags: git

Here is what I have done so far. And what I'm trying to do is merge the first and second commits into a single commit before I push (have not added remote repository yet).

```
$ git init

$ vim myprogram

$ git add myprogram && git commit -m "Initial commit"

$ vim README.md

$ git add README.md && git commit -m "Added readme"

$git log --pretty=oneline
b8e2979 Added readme
a579d65 Initial commit

$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream HEAD~2
```

What have I done wrong that is causing the fatal error.

If this exact question has been asked, please flag it and provide a link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to use the `--root` option:

> ... Rebase all commits reachable from `<branch>`, instead of limiting them with an `<upstream>`. This allows you to **rebase the root commit(s) on a branch**. ...

```
git rebase -i --root
```